# 'this' is undefined when I call a function from my service

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this call on my `component page`

```
this.timerSessionService.startTimer(this.finish.bind(this), this.onSynchronice);
```

well, it works great with the `this.finish`, but when I call `onSynchronice` from my `Service` it still works and goes to my `component` the problem comes when on my `component` I try to call a function that is inside of my component using `.this`, it says:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property 'pew' of undefined

this is because on my `onSynchronice` function I use `.this` and then it says it does not exist... how do I fix it?

### On my component

```
onSynchronice(pew) {
  console.log(pew["pew"]); //Works perfect
  this.pew= pew; //Crashes because of .this
  this.anyfunction(pew); //It crashes and says the same, anyfunction() does not exist, even if it exists
}
```

Comment: Post all of the component's code, because nobody can guess what is causing your issue without having a full picture of the context.

Comment: It's too long @TsvetanGanev, what do you need? I guess I put it the most important stuff, I call the function from my component, and then from the services I call onSynchronice passing pew as an atribute, and it works, but when I try to assign that attribute to a variable of my component it crashes.

Comment: use arrow functions to keep the context the same for your callbacks.

Comment: How do I use arrow function on this case?

Comment: If @toskv does not post his suggestion as an answer, I will. :-)

Comment: @ConnorsFan do it, maybe it's not the solution use arrow function, who knows :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define `onSynchronice` as an arrow function:

```
onSynchronice = (pew) => {
    console.log(pew["pew"]);
    this.pew= pew;
    this.anyfunction(pew);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, if I do this now it crashes a variable from my component printing on `html`

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. Does `this.pew = pew` work now?

Comment: I'll fix it, don't worry, that was the point on this question, thanks mate it works ;)

Comment: one question if I do this : `this.timerSessionService.startTimer(this.finish.bind(this), this.onSynchronice.bind(this));` will do the same work?

Comment: Good question. I never use `bind`. You can try it and tell me. :-)